# In the admin, how can you list thumbnails instead of titles for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, wp-admin, advanced-custom-fields, thumbnails

I'm using Custom Post Types UI and Advanced Custom Fields Pro to create a 'Portfolio Images' post type. The custom fields include Image as well as some others. When clicking on 'All Portfolio Images' in the admin, is it possible to show a list of thumbnail images instead of the post titles?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into adding a custom post column for that post type which shows the image you'd like to.

See this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column).

edit: here's a working example.

```
function add_column_header_298736( $defaults ) {
    $defaults[ 'image' ] = 'Image';

    return $defaults;
}
add_filter( 'manage_results_posts_columns', 'add_column_header_298736', 20 );

function add_column_content_298736( $column_name, $post_id ) {

    if ( $column_name == 'image' ) {
        // do stuff to retrieve your image
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_{your_post_type}_posts_custom_column', 'add_column_content_298736', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: Yes, that's it, but it might help OP if you elaborate a bit instead of just dumping a link.

Comment: Fair enough... 
*edit code doesn't work in here, will edit initial reply.